# How to I find the length of a side on a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

How do I find *line AB* in this if *ac* is $6cm$, and *bc* is $14cm$? angle A is $59^\circ$, B is $55^\circ$, and C is $66^\circ$. (not to scale)

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: It is between 8cm and 20cm unless there are any more restrictions.

Comment: @amWhy, 'scalene' nature  is one

Comment: What, @lab? I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Well, when adding the condition 'scalene', only 14cm is prohibited

Comment: @amWhy, the title of the file had 'scalene'

Comment: Given two sides, you need one angle to define the triangle.  If the angle is not between the sides, there may be two solutions.  If you define two (or three) angles, you have overspecified the problem and there may not (as here) be a solution at all.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: with the added angles given, use the Law of Sines to compute the length of $\overline{AB}$. Taking angle B to be $55^\circ$

For angles A, B, C of a triangle, with $a$ being the length of the side opposite angle A, and so on, we have the following equality of ratios:
$$\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac {c}{\sin C}\tag{Law of Sines}$$

$$\frac {14}{\sin(59^\circ)} = \frac {|AB|}{\sin(66^\circ)} = \frac{6}{\sin(55^\circ)}$$

As you can see, the first and last fraction are not equal, ***so no such triangle can exist***.

Comment: what is the law of sines? I'm 13. (BTW I know algebra so you can use it to show me.)

Comment: Now that added conditions have been imposed, there is no such triangle.

Comment: Let me know if knowing the law of sines relationship helps. It is extremely useful in cases where a triangle exists, and you know some angles, but not all, in combination with some sides, but not all...And **it doesn't require that the triangle be a right triangle** to use it!! I applies to **all** triangles, when sufficient (consistent) information exists.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information, you cannot say. With no knowledge about the angles, there are infinitely many triangles that have the lengths of two legs as $6$ and $14$.

Answer (score 0):

If $AB=x$ cm

we need

$x+14>6,$ which is always true as $x>0$

$ 14+6>x \implies  20>x$

$6+x>14\implies x>8$

So, $x$ can assume any values between  $(8,20)$

Comment: I think you mean in the last line: x+6>14 so x>8

Comment: @user45878, yes, I meant that.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From $\frac {AB}{\sin C}=\frac{BC}{\sin A}$ we get $AB=13.14$cm.
From $\frac {AB}{\sin C}=\frac{AC}{\sin B}$ we get $AB=6.28$cm.
Note that not only the results differ significantly, the second one even dos not obey the triangle inequality. Where did you get your numbers from?

Comment: I made them up!